# A Stupid Question Maybe - EigenNDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, packages

I would like to find out how accurate and how useful the chebyshev (collocation?) method is in finding many eigenvalues to a second-order ODE in one go. Specifically, I used the Mathematica package "Eigen" which may be found here: http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/8762/

The version of Mathematica I used is, Mathematica 10.0 Student Edition.

There's an example notebook Examples.nb on the above mentioned webpage. The strange thing is that while the line of code

```
esys = EigenNDSolve[{-(1/2) \[Xi]''[x] + 
      1/2 x^2 \[Xi][x] == \[Omega] \[Xi][x], \[Xi][-10] == 
     0, \[Xi][10] == 0}, \[Xi], {x, -10, 10}, \[Omega]];
```

works fine, when it's changed to

```
esys = EigenNDSolve[{-(1/2) \[Xi]''[x] + 
      1/2 x^2 \[Xi][x] == \[Omega] \[Xi][x], \[Xi][-10] == 
     0, \[Xi][10.5] == 0}, \[Xi], {x, -10, 10.5}, \[Omega]];
```

, the error "EigenNDSolve::numeq: Number of variables does not match number of equations!" was thrown. Of course, it might be true that the chebyshev method as coded works only for $[-x,x]$, for which BCs are prescribed at $x$ and $-x$, but I didn't see that in the documentation. It seems that the "." in "10.5" in the code causes some trouble. The same thing happens when

```
aa = -10.0;
bb = 10.0;    
esys = EigenNDSolve[{-(1/2) \[Xi]''[x] + 
              1/2 x^2 \[Xi][x] == \[Omega] \[Xi][x], \[Xi][aa] == 
             0, \[Xi][bb] == 0}, \[Xi], {x, aa, bb}, \[Omega]];
```

Of course I'm just a novice in the use of Mathematica; it may be that floating point numbers should not be input as such, or that I did something wrong when I imported the package. So where's the problem?

PS: I seemed not to get the error when I was using Mathematica 9. Indeed I've used the package "Eigen" before and it worked as expected.

Comment: "It may be that floating point numbers should not be input as such", this explanation isn't wrong, and I think the failure will be reproduced in any version of _Mathematica_. To fix the problem, the easiest way is to change the floating point numbers into exact numbers i.e. change `10.5` etc. to `105/10` etc.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. The way to get around the difficulty is unexpectedly easy, albeit somewhat inconvenient.

Comment: In fact you can consider modifying the source code a little. (Add a `Rationalize[……, 0]` somewhere etc. )